# How to install Anaconda in such a way that there are no conflicts between the paths I already have?

Tags: installation, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-18.04, anaconda3

I have downloaded Anaconda and run the installation as follows:

```
Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3
by running conda init? [yes|no]
[no] >>> no

You have chosen to not have conda modify your shell scripts at all.
To activate conda's base environment in your current shell session:

eval "$(/home/paul/Documents/Work/programs/anaconda3/bin/conda shell.YOUR_SHELL_NAME hook)" 

To install conda's shell functions for easier access, first activate, then:

conda init

If you'd prefer that conda's base environment not be activated on startup, 
   set the auto_activate_base parameter to false: 

conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

My idea is that conda will start and run whenever I want, in a special enviroment. What would be the next steps?

All the best,

Comment: It sounds like you really just want to disable the **base** auto-activation. You still want the `conda init` - it’s inconvenient without it. It adds some shell functions, and adds only the `condabin/` directory to PATH, which minimally includes the `conda`, `conda-build`, and similar essential entry points. Stuff that you should not have coming from PATH anywhere else on your system.

Comment: Also, consider Miniconda or Miniforge instead of Anaconda. A large **base** environment had been found among experienced users to be problematic.